# ¿Cómo agregar los objetos de una matriz dinámica en un ListBox?

Tags: vba

Quiero agregar los elementos de una matriz dinámica en un ListBox. Probé el siguiente código:

`LateReservistsUserForm` :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i

    i = 0
    With LateReservistsUserForm.lbOutOfDate
        For i = LBound(Array("arrayOReservistsOutOfDate")) To UBound(Array("arrayOReservistsOutOfDate"))
            .AddItem arrayOReservistsOutOfDate(i)
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Desafortunadamente me sale el siguiente error con la linea `.AddItem`:

```
El tipo no coincide
```

Comment: `arrayOReservistsOutOfDate(i)`es una cadena?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho No, es una matriz dinámica